# Save in Excel error - 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, dataframe, k-means

I tried to save the result in excel, but I got the error - 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'.
I have no trouble running the whole code except the last line (saving result).

Can you help me spot the mistakes? Thank you

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy.spatial import distance

df1=pd.read_csv("Clus_readinFile.csv", index_col="Site_ID")
df1.head(5)

# Standardization (z-score)
scaler = StandardScaler()
df_std = scaler.fit_transform(df1)
df_std

centroids_All = []
for cluster in range(1,15):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_jobs = -1, n_clusters = cluster, init='k-means++')
    kmeans.fit(df_std)
    counts = dict(Counter(kmeans.labels_))
    counts = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient='index',  columns=['Stores'])
    centroids_deno = pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_),columns= df1.columns)
    centroids_deno['Stores'] = counts['Stores']
    centroids_All.append(centroids_deno)

centroids_All.to_excel("centroidsAllResult.xlsx")
```

Comment: `centroids_All` is a list. lists don't have a `to_excel()` function. What do you actually want to save to excel? It should be a dataframe

Comment: Hi Pranav, Yes I want to save it as a dataframe. I feel that I already transformed it into a dataframe by pd.DataFrame. How do I need to change it? Thank you

Comment: `centroids_deno` is your dataframe. You're doing `to_excel()` on `centroids_All`.

Comment: Helpful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation of your code. The contents of the for loop must be indented. See [formatting help](/help/format) for help on how to correctly formatyour code using code fences.

Comment: Hi Pranav, if it is centroids_deno, the result only displays one possible number of the cluster (even I change centroids_deno.append(centroids_deno)); Instead, I want to append and save the results when cluster =1, 2, 3,....,15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to_excel()` function is defined under pandas objects and can be called by a pandas DataFrame object.  However, the object `centroids_All` that you want to call the `to_excel()` function is defined as a list. Although you appended pandas Dataframe into the list `centroids_All` it still is not a pandas DataFrame by itself.  Hence the error.

You can use [Dataframe.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) to append/concatenate your resulting DataFrame's within the loop instead of using list append.  Then use the resulting DataFrame object to call `to_excel()`

Simply change your code `centroids_All = []` to:

```
centroids_All = pd.DataFrame()
```

This is to create an empty pandas DataFrame instead of empty list.

The code to append the DataFrame needs only slight change (by luck, similar syntax as your code to append list).  `ignore_index=True` is added into the append() call so as to re-serialize the index.  The resulting code is:

```
centroids_All = centroids_All.append(centroids_deno, ignore_index=True)
```

Note to reassign the appended result back to the consolidating dataframe.

Comment: Hi Seabean, I see what you mean. How do I need to change it if I want to append and save the results when cluster =1, 2, 3,....,15? Thank you

Comment: Use pd.concat. See the doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: @Qianru Song, you can also refer to DataFrame.append() function.  Document [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append)

Comment: @QianruSong  Hope you have already solved your problem.  I have further edited the suggested codes to fine-tune it (based on previous works I've done before).